# Problem when fill fields into Adobe echo sign

Tags: email, field-mapping

Got this message on email:

> ```
> Organization Name: 
> Organization ID: 00D36000000ZDMDEA4
> User Name: Igor Stosic
> User ID: 00536000002qq2IAAQ
> Agreement Name: /
> Agreement ID: a1F36000001hpPiEAI
>
>
> Failed to map data field: System.TypeException 
> Invalid date: July 7, 1980 (echosign_dev1) 818 
> Failed to map data field: System.TypeException Invalid double: 20,000 (echosign_dev1) 843 
> Failed to map data field: System.TypeException Invalid double: 27,000 (echosign_dev1) 843
> ```

When i set value of number in this format 20,000 but if i set 20 000 got no email error. Main problem is that i will not fill this document, user will and they don't know in what format it should be.

Comment: You'll want to refer to the users to the manual.

Comment: Yes, clients will do this manual.